# Find out all the date formats from whole Web Page

Tags: javascript

I need to find out all the date format from the whole HTML page and compare them with the current date and alert or print a message that how many days are left for the expiry of promo code or (need to find the difference from the current date).

In my code, there is a for loop in which I am trying to find out another date format, here I am getting the invalid date format when I am trying to compare this date with the current one.

```
 var get_string = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].innerText; 

 var find_month = /([\d]{1,2} (?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)? 

 |Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?

 |Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?) [\d]{4})/gim

 function formatDate(date){

   var monthNames = [
  "January", "February", "March",
  "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October",
  "November", "December"
    ];
    var day = date.getDate();

    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();

    var year = date.getFullYear(); 

    return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
}
var dates_get = formatDate(new Date());
var ToDate = new Date(dates_get);
do {
    match_value = find_month.exec(get_string);  
    if (match_value) {
        var match_data = match_value[1];
        var UserDate = new Date(match_data);
        const diffTime = Math.abs(UserDate.getTime() - ToDate.getTime());
        const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
        //dates_data.push(match_data);
        if(UserDate.getTime() == ToDate.getTime()){
            alert('Your Promo Code will expire today.');
        }
        // check if date is less than today date
        else if (UserDate.getTime() <= ToDate.getTime()){
            alert('Promo Code has been expire');
        }
        // check how many days left in expiring the promo code.
        else{
            alert('Promo Code is going to expire in next ' + diffDays + ' days');
        }
    }
} while (match_value);
var array_convert = [];
var result_date = get_string.match(/\d{2}([\/.-])\d{2}\1\d{4}/g);
var array_convert = result_date;
var get_length = array_convert.length;
for(i=0;i<get_length;i++){
    var data_alert = result_date[i];        
    var date_compare = new Date(data_alert);    
    alert(date_compare);
    // here I need to do the same as above(For showing the promo code)
    // This is giving invalid date
}
```

Getting Invalid date format when I try to do the same as I did in the above Promo code section.
Here is the example for the paragraph:

"Lorem ipsum dolor  sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.
This cashback is on 28 August 2019
This cashback is on 2019-06-11
This cashback is on 26 September 2019
This cashback is on 18/09/2019.
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be almost impossible to write a code that detects *virtually any* type of date in you whole website code. Here are just two reasons for my statement:

1) The [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) provides an international standard for date and time formats and is - well - pretty extensive...

2) In various languages, people use different date and time notations. So if you want to support internationalization it would become even more complicated.

---

Do you have any information about the format(s) used in your promo codes? Otherwise you could only try to support the most dominant notations.

ECMAScript provides a [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to create an internal date (and time) representation from any valid date input string. You could use the [documentation of ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-objects) (see section "20.3 Date Objects") as a starting point how Date objects can be parsed. Maybe you'll find some source implementation as reference which you can then use yourself.